# Multiple Web Applications in spring boot project

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Using spring 4 and maven, I'm used to creating layered applications where the sub projects compile into jars and the root project compiles into a war.  Ex

```
  Web Layer
      |
Service Layer
      |
  Dao Layer

(Shared Common Project)
```

Using this architecture, I could also create 2 Web applications that have a common parent pom and share the same sub projects

```
  Web Layer      Admin Web Layer
         \        /
             |
        Service Layer
             |
          Dao Layer

(Shared Common Project)
```

Is it possible to achieve the same thing in spring boot? I do not want to combine the 2 web projects. They serve completely different purposes. They have different login mechanisms, differn't users, differen't roles etc.

**Clarification**

If I were building this application with spring 4 and maven, the web applications would be compiled into 2 wars. Then they could be run on a single server on the same port. I am trying to match this configuration with spring boot, but since spring-boot has tomcat embedded into it, I'm not sure how both of these applications could be run on the same instance.

Comment: What would be the point in doing this ?

Comment: They are 2 different  web applications that share many of the same services, but nothing in terms of views and security.

Comment: There's nothing in Spring Boot that stops you from doing what you have described. It sounds like you need two separate Spring Boot applications that have dependencies on the common sub-projects.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to figure out how to do. I can't find any examples of it. Also, I'm not sure how I would be able to run both applications at the same time.

Comment: Or create 3 spring boot apps. One which exposes your services as REST endpoints on top of which you build 2 other applications the web and admin applications.

Comment: Have you found a way to do this at the end? I am facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Create a separate project module for Service layer.
2. Create a separate project module for DAO Layer.
3. Create a SPRING BOOT APP for Web Layer, Web Layer depends on Service Layer and DAO Layer.
4. Create a SPRING BOOT APP for Admin Web Layer, Admin Web Layer depends on Service Layer and DAO Layer.

With this design you will be able to run Web Layer and Admin Web Layer separately and distinctly but at the same time using common service and dao layer.

Comment: How can I run them both at the same time? If I run the command mvn spring-boot:run on the web module, then try to run it again on the admin module, won't I get an error because the port is already in use?

Comment: if you are having two different spring boot applications and have application.properties or application.yml. Define this property there server.port = 8010 or whatever port you like (which is not already in use).

Comment: In the example I gave, the web applications would be compiled into 2 wars using spring 4 and maven. Then they could be run on a server on the same port. I am trying to match this configuration. That is what I'm trying to figure out how to do, but since spring-boot has tomcat embedded into it, I'm not sure how both of these applications could be run on the same instance.